# Behaviour of persistent messages on a mirrored in a RabbitMQ cluster

Tags: rabbitmq, synchronization

I am trying to figure out whether in a mirrored queue that only has persistant messages, is it still possible to lose messages during the re-synchronisation process.

If I have a queue mirrored across a two nodes (to simplify the example).
The exchange and queue is durable and all the messages marked as persistant.

The Master Queue is on Node 1
The Mirrored Queue is on Node 2

The scenario is

1. Initially the queues are synchronised
2. Node 2 goes down
3. Node 2 Recovers
4. Before Node 2 synchronises Node 1 is lost
5. Node 2 becomes the master

At step 3 Node 2 recovers, does it load the messages from the message store that it had persisted, or will it start with no messages and start synchronising (by the two standard resynchronsisation methods)

In the case where a queue is mirrored, does each queue have it's own message store.

If this scenario does lose messages, is there a scenario where this can be avoided

Comment: Read this: https://jack-vanlightly.com/blog/2018/9/10/how-to-lose-messages-on-a-rabbitmq-cluster

Comment: Thanks Luke, this is where my question originally arose from

Comment: That document also contains configurations that prevent the scenario you describe. Read it carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that if this scenario occurs, the messages will be lost regardless of your configuration. To mitigate the problem, the solution would be to ensure that

- Ensure messages are persisted
- Queues and Exchanges are durable
- Ensure consumer acknowledgements are used and that it is set to only
  acknowledge when the message has been committed to the master and all
  the mirrored replicas.
- Ensure there are an appropriate number of mirrored replicas so as to
  avoid getting to the situation where you don't have a synchronized
  queue

There will be a throughput performance hit.